# What is the difference between SaveMode and FlushMode in Spring Session?

Tags: java, spring, spring-session

Spring Session Has two enumerations one called `SaveMode` and one called `FlushMode` the reference docs don't make any mention of SaveMode and Flush mode. The javadoc descriptions sound very similar.

- What exactly do Save Mode and Flush Mode control?
- What are the use cases where SaveMode and Flush Mode need to be set explicitly?

**SaveMode**

```java
/**
 * Supported modes of tracking and saving session changes to session store.
 *
 * @author Rob Winch
 * @author Vedran Pavic
 * @since 2.2.0
 */
public enum SaveMode {

    /**
     * Save only changes made to session, for instance using
     * {@link Session#setAttribute(String, Object)}. In highly concurrent environments,
     * this mode minimizes the risk of attributes being overwritten during processing of
     * parallel requests.
     */
    ON_SET_ATTRIBUTE,

    /**
     * Same as {@link #ON_SET_ATTRIBUTE} with addition of saving attributes that have been
     * read using {@link Session#getAttribute(String)}.
     */
    ON_GET_ATTRIBUTE,

    /**
     * Always save all session attributes, regardless of the interaction with the session.
     * In highly concurrent environments, this mode increases the risk of attributes being
     * overwritten during processing of parallel requests.
     */
    ALWAYS

}
```

**FlushMode**

```java
/**
 * Supported modes of writing the session to session store.
 *
 * @author Rob Winch
 * @author Vedran Pavic
 * @since 2.2.0
 */
public enum FlushMode {

    /**
     * Only writes to session store when {@link SessionRepository#save(Session)} is
     * invoked. In a web environment this is typically done as soon as the HTTP response
     * is committed.
     */
    ON_SAVE,

    /**
     * Writes to session store as soon as possible. For example
     * {@link SessionRepository#createSession()} will write the session to session store.
     * Another example is that setting an attribute using
     * {@link Session#setAttribute(String, Object)} will also write to session store
     * immediately.
     */
    IMMEDIATE

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Now look at the [Spring Session documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5):

`flushMode`: Allows specifying when data is written to Redis. The default is only when save is invoked on `ReactiveSessionRepository`. A value of `FlushMode.IMMEDIATE` writes to Redis as soon as possible.

Flip through the source code, specifically in RedisSession -> flushImmediateIfNecessary() this function call.

As for the role of [`SaveMode`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/blob/c88456a183d7c72f4d0b2bf1400c33c3be72c983/spring-session-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/session/SaveMode.java), I am also looking for answers.